# Get Browser Tabs and Three Control Options in Same Rows

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, titlebar, brave

I have switched to **kubuntu 22.04** from **windows** and I am liking it. But the fact that Three Control options **( minimize, maximize, close)** are taking its own row is very annoying.

> I do not need title at window's titlebar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql97U.png)

like This Firefox.

But Brave browser is quite good with its own setup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSsVe.png)

How can I make firefox and all other windows like those things in a single row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, click the hamburger menu (≡), then "More tools" - "Customize toolbar". In the bottom left corner, remove the checkbox before "Title bar".

Comment: Thanks vanadium bro. This is what I was looking for.